# Ошибка CORS при обращении к API на Laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, requests, cors, fetch

Написал простой API для домашнего проекта и загрузил его под доменом api.anaxita.ru , но возникла следующая проблема, после загрузки на хостинг.

Делаю fetch запрос с localhost на удалённый API на Laravel 7, который принимает токен и возвращает коллекцию в json:

```js
fetch(`http://api.anaxita.ru/api/products`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      'Authorization': 'Bearer wrSWsPWD8Cs8I7oUnoePAbs2u8MutkSXbmo8Kk4P',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
  })
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(function(data) {
    console.log('Request successful', data);
    return data;
  })
  .catch(function(error) {
    console.log('Request failed', error)
  })
```

Получаю следующий ответ в браузере:
[image: Ошибка CORS]

Перейдя в network вижу, что браузер отправил 2 запроса (или попытался отправить):
[image: requests errors]

### В первом запросе (failed) следующие заголовки:

```
Response  headers:

Provisional headers are shown
Authorization: Bearer wrSWsPWD8Cs8I7oUnoePAbs2u8MutkSXbmo8Kk4P
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://fatapp/views/registration/sign-up.php
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36
```

### Во втором запросе следующие заголовки:

Request headers:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Access-Control-Request-Headers: authorization,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: GET
Connection: keep-alive
Host: api.anaxita.ru
Origin: http://fatapp
Referer: http://fatapp/views/registration/sign-up.php
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.83 Safari/537.36
```

Response headers:

```
Allow
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 224
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date: Fri, 11 Sep 2020 13:07:13 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=2, max=100
Server: Apache/2
```

### Что я пробовал

1. В файле config/cors.php  прописаны следующие разрешения

   ```
    return [
    'paths' => ['*'],
    'allowed_methods' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins' => ['*'],
    'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],
    'allowed_headers' => ['*'],
    'exposed_headers' => [],
    'max_age' => 0,
    'supports_credentials' => false,
   ```

   ];
2. Пробовал создавать отдельный глобальный middleware и прописать там заголовки
3. Пробовал добавить файл .htaccess и прописать там заголовки
4. Обращаться по http а не https
5. Использовать в запросе mode: no-corse

**Локально запросы проходят между фронтом и беком проходят корректно.
Запросы из POSTMAN проходят удачно получают код 200.**

#### Прошу вашего совета.

*Токен, указанный в запросе, валиден и его можно использовать для запросов.*

Comment: А это ваш http://api.anaxita.ru/api/products вервис?

Comment: Доступ к нему у вас есть?

Comment: Да, мой сервис, доступ есть.

Comment: Вам помимо cors заголовка нужно разрешить Authorization в заголовке. Под рукой ссылки нет, наберите cors Authorization  Bearer  problem

Comment: Сделайте отладку вашего кода и убедитесь что на OPTIONS запрос ваш сервер отдаёт нужные заголовки. После этого заливайте на сервер.

Comment: В конце вопроса я сообщил, что локально работает корректно.
Запросы на OPTIONS я получаю.
Сейчас пробую загрузить на другой хостинг где больше прав по настройке веб-сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решилась переездом на новый хостинг.
Прошлый хостинг не разрешал OPTIONS заголовки и не давал возможности их разрешить вручную.

Answer (score 1):

[CORS](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) - это к сервису (http://api.anaxita.ru/api/products) либо проксируйте через бек сервер.

> CORS - технология современных браузеров, которая позволяет
> предоставить веб-странице доступ к ресурсам другого домена. Является
> альтернативой JSONP, бывшей до некоторого времени основным способом
> преодоления ограничений, наложенных в правиле доменного ограничения
> относительно XSS-запросов, преодолевая неустранимое ограничение JSONP
> — невозможность получения данных методом POST.
>
> Сама технология достаточно проста. Есть три домена, желающие загрузить
> ресурсы с сервера Z. Для того чтобы это стало возможным, веб-серверу
> Z, который отдает контент, достаточно указать **в заголовке ответа**
> Access-Control-Allow-Origin

Comment: В пункт 1 части "Я пробовал" я сообщил, что на стороне сервиса разрешены все заголовки т.е стоит заголовок "Access-Control-Allow-Origin * "